# How citation goes to next page using beamer overleaf.com code?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber

I am using the following template for the slide presentation, but I am not able to see the citation goes on the next page. Please inform me what the problem with the following code is? But remember that I am not sure the following code makes the problem it may occur because of other portions of code.

```
    \section*{References} %You can remove this if you do not want to use it
    % \nocite{Djairo} \nocite{PhilPanof} \nocite{Fleming} \nocite{Shankar}
    \begin{frame}{References}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
```

I just want to see the whole references cited by me that can cover more than one slide I have no problem.
You may see the whole code by the following link:

Anyone with this link can edit this project
https://www.overleaf.com/8862493198fmktstqnvbvj
Anyone with this link can view this project
https://www.overleaf.com/read/tkwwxgccrnjt

Comment: Although this doesn't sound Overleaf specific, if you get in touch with support@overleaf.com we'll take a look and may be able to offer some advice (I'm on the support team). My feeling is that you should never post your edit link on the public internet like this, I'd strongly recommend that you remove it and turn-off link sharing.
If you do want to ask the community about this, I think you should provide the code that produces the problem output directly (not in an Overleaf project) - ideally a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Change the background and text color. The dark background does not allow to read the text of the references list.

**(2)** Add some `\cite{citationkey}` to be listed or use `\nocite{citationkey}` to add references to the list of references,  (from the file `bib.bib`) or use `\nocite{*} to get all.

**(3)** Compile + run `biber` + compile twice more. `Biber` should finish with `Process exited normally`.

[image: a]

This is a simplification of your code. Note the use of  `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]` to allow a long list of references.

There were added 8 references from the file `bib.bib` of your project.
(or use `\nocite{*}` to list all of them, 60 frames)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\input{chapters/preamble}   

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

\title{My Presentation} %->->->->-> Check hyperref title <-<-<-<-<-
\subtitle{And Some Things About It}
\author[F.de Tal]{\textcolor{yellow}{Fulano Ciclano de Tal}}
\institute[IMUFSP]{
    \textcolor{white}{Institute of Mathematics}%
    \\%
    \textcolor{white}{Federal University of Some Place}%
} %You can change the Institution if you are from somewhere else
\date{Feb. 30, 2142}
%\logo{\includegraphics[width= 0.05\textwidth]{images/logo.png}}


\begin{document}
    
    \frame{\titlepage}  
    
    \section*{References} 
    
     % added 8 references from bib.bib
    \nocite{takemura2017input} \nocite{muramatsu2012arbitrary} \nocite{liao2017pose} \nocite{casia}  <<<<<       
    \nocite{deng2017fusion} \nocite{yang2016relative} \nocite{tafazzoli2010model} \nocite{paszke2019pytorch}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] % to allow long list of references
        \frametitle{References}
          \printbibliography
    \end{frame}

    \section{}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \centering
            \Huge\bfseries
        \textcolor{yellow}{The End}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Used `biblatex.sty    2022/02/02 v3.17` and  `Biber 2.17`

Comment: +1: clear and nice structure